# Generate random textboxes to show random numbers

Tags: vb.net, random, textbox

I'm trying to create a program  which selects textboxes from the list at random and generate random numbers from 1 to 5 in those textboxes,
but with no success. I have 10 textboxes named Textbox1- Textbox10, 1 textbox named TxB1 and 1 button. In TxB1 user should specify number of selected at random textboxes. 
For example: user has specified number 4 in  TxB1, 
has clicked button1 and then numbers from 1 to 5 should appear in 4 different textboxes choosed at random. 
Here is the code I tried with no luck...

```
    Dim rn As New Random 
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            Dim index2 As Integer = rn.Next(1, TxB1.Text)
            Dim MyListOfTextBoxes() As TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8, TextBox9, TextBox10}
            For index = 0 To 9
                Dim RandomNumberAHigh As Integer = 10
                Dim RandomNumberALow As Integer = 1
                Dim Random As Integer = 0

                For i As Integer = 0 To index2
                    MyListOfTextBoxes(index2).Text = Int((RandomNumberAHigh - RandomNumberALow + 1) * Rnd() + RandomNumberALow)
                Next
            Next
        End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to clarify what you are trying to do -  as is it sounds like you want to put a range a numbers (not random numbers) into random textboxes (which are are not dynamically generated).  Then turn on `Option Strict`, and dont depend on luck to make code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a number of unique, random selections from a list then, as long as the list is not too large, I would recommend ordering the list randomly and then taking the appropriate number of items from the beginning of that list.  In your case:

```
Dim rng As New Random
Dim allTextBoxes = {TextBox1, TextBox2, ..., TextBox10}
Dim selectedTextBoxes = allTextBoxes.OrderBy(Function(tb) rng.NextDouble()).
                                     Take(numberOfTextBoxes).
                                     ToArray()
```

Displaying a random number of each is then just a matter of looping through the second array and setting its `Text` based on a number generated by the same `Random` object.

```
For Each tb In selectedTextBoxes
    tb.Text = rng.Next(1, 6).ToString()
Next
```

Note that you don't even need the `ToArray` call in the first code snippet if the list is just going to be the subject of a `For Each` loop.  The result of `Take` can be used for that.